# Deleting row from database from datagridview value

Tags: c#, datagridview, sql-server-ce

I have an unbound DataGridView which displays DataTable data selected on the previous form. If I wish to remove a DataRow from the DataGridView, I'd like it to update the DataBase. I have some code, but it doesn't work properly, it just deletes the first row, instead of deleting the selected row (which I want to delete because of its value). Is there a way to obtain the cell value and pass through a query to delete it from the DateBase? I'm using SqlCe 3.5

```
private void removeBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


            string tableName = Data["Quotation Name"].ToString().Trim(); //gets the table name 
            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to remove this item? ", "Confirm Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {   for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 0; i++){

                string constring = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\LWADataBase.sdf";
                string Query = "delete from [" + tableName + "] where [Item Name] = @item ";
                SqlCeConnection conDataBase = new SqlCeConnection(constring);
                SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(Query, conDataBase);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@item", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                try
                {

                    conDataBase.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();



                    //displays a system error message if a problem is found
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

                }
                getTable(); //loads the table into the DGV



            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void removeBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string tableName = Data["Quotation Name"].ToString().Trim(); //gets the table name 
        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to remove this item? ", "Confirm Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {

            foreach (DataGridViewRow r in quotation_NameDataGridView.SelectedRows)
            {

                string constring = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\LWADataBase.sdf";
                string Query = "delete from [" + tableName + "] where [Item Name] like @item";
                SqlCeConnection conDataBase = new SqlCeConnection(constring);
                SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(Query, conDataBase);
                if (r.Cells[0] != null)
                {

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@item", r.Cells[0].Value.ToString());

                    try
                    {
                        conDataBase.Open();
                        int res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        conDataBase.Close();
                        //displays a system error message if a problem is found
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

                    }
                }
                getTable(); //loads the table into the DGV

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @user3521452 Updated the answer, the parameter must be sorrounded by single quotes '

Comment: Thanks buddy, I'll see how I get on.

Comment: Still nothing happens when I click the button

Comment: @user3521452 Updated the answer, forget the single quotes, add an if to avoid a null reference exception and close the connection

Comment: Still nothing, could you post your complete code for the button click event to see where I'm going wrong

Comment: Make sure you select the full row clicking at the row header, make sure you are checking the right database file inside the bin folder, (int res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()) "res" will give you the number of rows affected.

Comment: Works perfectly when selecting the row from the row header. Is there a way to make it select the whole row from a clicking a cell?

Comment: @user3521452 You can set SelectionMode property of the datagridview to FullRowSelect